# Securing physical servers with an NSX-T gateway firewall in active/active edge routing scenario

Tags: vmware, virtualization

So my plan is to secure a set of physical servers in a private network against the entire NSX-T workload domain, without buying an additional hardware firewall, since we have massive edge capacity left, but no money. :/

So intuitively I would just add an NSX gateway firewall, just like it's described in this blog post:

https://blogs.vmware.com/networkvirtualization/2020/08/the-nsx-t-gateway-firewall-secures-physical-servers.html/

But there it's the easy case, when the firewall is just added to the default T0, which I can't do due to our active/active setup. So I would have to add an additional active/passive T0 and connect it to the existing T0.

But how do I now force traffic to my private network through the additional T0 including the gateway firewall?

Apprently this is impossible to achieve without bridging only the second T0 to the private network's vlan and omitting the route via the physical BGP router. Or is there a chance?

Answer (score 1):

So if the private network is routed via the physical BGP uplink router, there is indeed no way, but to hide this route on the physical BGP. This wouldn't make too much sense anyways, so let's consider the case where it doesn't.

Then there are apparently two solutions to this task, with the first probably being the more straight forward one:

1. Deploy an additional service edge (active/passive) and then add a service gateway and the gateway firewall to any T1. The corresponding T1 service router will then be deployed on the service edge (you have to pick one in the deployment wizard). Now we might only have to add a prefix filter on the NSX BGP uplink, if we want to hide the private network to the external uplink network.
2. Configure L2 bridging: [Vmware Docs](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-NSX-T-Data-Center/3.1/administration/GUID-7B21DF3D-C9DB-4C10-A32F-B16642266538.html). Create an L2 bridge in any segment and add the gateway firewall to this segment's T1 uplink or add a bridge firewall to the bridge's VDS. Then optionally apply the prefix filter for the bridged LAN on the BGP uplink.

Answer (score 0):

an upcoming update will let you use A/A and firewall (stateful). VMware is working on it. That simply set stateful services to use even with A/A routing setup.